# How do i specify a queryset to a django form widget in a generic UpdateView

Tags: python, django, forms

My model :

```python
class TarifGe(models.Model):
    mise_a_disposition = models.ForeignKey(MiseADisposition)
    tarif_son = models.ForeignKey("TarifGe", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, default=None, blank=True)
```

My View :

```python
class TarifGeUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = TarifGe
    template_name = "tarifs_form.html"
    fields = ['tarif_son',]
```

tarif_fils is a TarifGe related object (father -> Son)

I would like to filter the initial values of the widget of de ***tarif_son*** field, to only have TarifGe objects that have the same ***mise_a_disposition*** field, instead of all the TarifGe objects.

Where and how can i specify the queryset for the "tarif_son" field's widget ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the [**`.get_form(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_form):

```
class TarifGeUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = TarifGe
    template_name = "tarifs_form.html"
    fields = ['tarif_son',]

    def get_form(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form = super().get_form(*args, **kwargs)
        form.fields['tarif_son'].queryset = TarifGe.objects.filter(
            mise_a_disposition=self.object.mise_a_disposition
        )
        return form
```

Comment: Thanks you very much ! I have tried this, but forgot the "*args, **kwargs" in function and super(). This solved my problem !